# Functions on regexp_replace result in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql, string-function

I have a database of addresses where acronyms have been separated with a space, I want to remove these space so I turned to trusty regular expressions.  However, I am struggling to perform a secondary function on the regexp result '\&' - I have checked the forums and docs and just cannot get this to work.  Example data I have is as follows:

- 'A V C Welding' should be 'AVC Welding'
- 'H S B C' should be 'HSBC'
- etc..

I have the following regexp:

```
trim(regexp_replace(organisation || ' ', '(([A-Z]\s){1}){2,}', replace('\&',' ',''), 'g'))
```

The `replace('\&',' ','')` is not having any effect at all, I just get the same string back.  I have tried other functions e.g. `lower('\&')` and none of these seem to work as expected.  Concatenation with || does work however.  I have tried casting the '\&' to text, tried `replace('' || '\&' || '',' ','')` - still, no joy.

Any advice would be much appreciated, I am sure the solution is something very simple but I just cannot see where to go next!

Comment: Hi Vivek - thanks for your reply, as per above I am expecting to be able to convert 'A V C Welding' to 'AVC Welding', 'H S B C' to HSBC etc.  It also needs to work for multiple acronyms so 'P D James & H S Wilson' would need to be 'PD James & HS Wilson'.  Any advice you can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: So to confim `select trim(regexp_replace('A V C Welding', '(([A-Z]\s){1}){2,}', replace('\&',' ',''), 'g'));` returns `A V C Welding` whereas I am expecting `AVC Welding`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with `replace('\&', ' ', '')`? It's a certain no-op this way.

Comment: Hi Patrick and thanks for the reply - the logic I am following is: 'find me all acronyms in a string, for each of this replace any whitespace' - so I was expecting that as `'\&` contains the matching text for the regexp that I would just be able to replace the spaces in this and get what I need  e.g. turn 'A V C Welding' into 'AVC Welding'.  If I use a fixed string instead of a function it works e.g. `select trim(regexp_replace('A V C Welding', '(([A-Z]\s){1}){2,}', 'XXX ', 'g'));` returns 'XXX Welding' so I don't think I am that far off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do with `\&` will never work. The `\&` pattern will replace the *entire pattern*, but you need a solution that works on individual parts.

What you need is to replace the pattern `CAPITAL-space` with just `CAPITAL` but only when followed by another capital which is not the start of a longer word. In other words: you need a *negative lookahead* and if the pattern is matched, then replace *only* the first atom of the replace string:

```
select regexp_replace('A V C Welding', '([A-Z]){1}(\s){1}(?![A-Z][a-z])', '\1', 'g');
```

You can replace the negative lookahead pattern with something broader if needed (such as no capital letter start, numbers, punctuation, etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much @Patrick, that is exactly what I was looking for, I have not used negative lookahead before, I will be sure to take this into account in the future, thanks again, you have made my day!